# How to use LAG and NUMTOYMINTERVAL in PARTITION?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset with 3 columns, `id, date, value`, here date has this format `DDMMYYYY`:

```
id    date            value
1     19/11/2020       10
1     19/10/2020       90
1     19/09/2020       87
1     19/07/2020       50
1     19/06/2020       17
```

I'm trying to use `PARTITION` to create partitions by `id` and order the value by `date`, and then create a new column with the `LAG` function, the issue is that there are missing `dates` that's why I'm trying to use  `NUMTOYMINTERVAL`, something like this:

```
SELECT ID, DATE, VALUE, LAG(VALUE, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE RANGE NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH') PRECEDING) AS VALUE_LAG
FROM TABLE
```

and the result I want is like this

```
id    date            value      value_lag
1     19/11/2020       10            90
1     19/10/2020       90            87
1     19/09/2020       87            NULL
1     19/07/2020       50            17
1     19/06/2020       17            NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, use `max()` with a `range` window frame:

```
select t.*,
       max(value) over (partition by id range between interval '1' day preceding and interval '1' day preceding) as pre_value
from t;
```

If your dates have slop in them (i.e. time components), you might want a more approximate solution:

```
select t.*,
       max(value) over (partition by id range between interval '36' hour preceding and interval '12' hour preceding) as pre_value
from t;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, in this case where I specify the date?, i'm new with this. thanks

Comment: @JuanCarlosJchr . . . The `range` window frame specification is determining the date.

Answer (score 1):

I coudn't use *lag function* on date with *range between clause*, here's another solution using *with clause*, *lag ()* and *months_between*

```
with sub as (
SELECT ID, some_DATE, some_VALUE
, LAG(some_DATE)
          over (partition by id order by some_DATE) prev_date
  FROM lag_num_test )
select s.id, s.some_date, 
  case 
    when (months_between(some_DATE, prev_date) = 1) 
      then lag(some_VALUE, 1) over (partition by id order by some_DATE) 
  end value_lag from sub s
order  by s.some_DATE desc;
```

And here's the table structure with inserts:

```
create table lag_num_test (
 id number,
 some_date date,
 some_value number
);
```

```
insert into lag_num_test(id, some_date, some_value) values (1, to_date('19/11/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 10);
insert into lag_num_test(id, some_date, some_value) values (1, to_date('19/10/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 90);
insert into lag_num_test(id, some_date, some_value) values (1, to_date('19/09/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 87);
insert into lag_num_test(id, some_date, some_value) values (1, to_date('19/07/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 50);
insert into lag_num_test(id, some_date, some_value) values (1, to_date('19/06/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 17);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT
    t.*,
    MAX(t.some_value) OVER(
        PARTITION BY t.id
        ORDER BY
            t.some_date
        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING
    ) AS pre_value
FROM
    lag_num_test t
ORDER BY
    t.some_date DESC;
```

this solution by **@Gordon Linoff** also works fine;
btw. @mathguy oracle will raise an exception (ORA-00905: missing keyword 00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword) when interval value is left without single quotes;